# IOptions binding with non-matching property names

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Is is possible to bind properties from a JSON file (appsettings.json) to a class that uses different property names?

```json
{
    "WebTarget": {
    "WebURL": "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
  }
}
```

```cs
public class MyServiceOptions
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

I want to take the `WebURL` setting and map it to the `Url` property in the options class. I've tried `[DataMember]` and `[JsonProperty]` but they don't work.

I know it's not ideal and the property names should match what's in the JSON but this one is a special case.

Comment: Short Answer: **Yes**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible. It requires a little more manual configuration

```
services.Configure<MyServiceOptions>(myOptions => {
    myOptions.Url = Configuration.GetSection("WebTarget").GetValue<string>("WebURL", string.Empty);
});
```

Reference [Configure simple options with a delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-simple-options-with-a-delegate-1)

Answer (score 14):

In ASP.NET 6, you can use [ConfigurationKeyNameAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationkeynameattribute?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) to bind properties that have different names than that of the object property.

```
public class MyServiceOptions
{
      [ConfigurationKeyName("WebURL")]    
      public string Url { get; set; }
}
```